# Rails Sample_App, Test errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

So following the Hartl sample app tutorials, and having a bit of trouble getting some tests to past regarding the relationship spec.

in my spec file I have

```
describe "follow methods" do

    before(:each) do
    @follower = User.create!( :name => "Example User", 
        :email => "user@example.com",
        :password => "foobar",
        :password_confirmation => "foobar"
    )
    @followed = User.create!( :name => "Example User", 
        :email => "user_five@example.com",
        :password => "foobar",
        :password_confirmation => "foobar"
    )
    @attr = { :followed_id => @followed.id }
    @relationship = @follower.relationships.create!(@attr)

    end
```

I know it's not the same as in the book however I'm not using FactoryGirl.

When using this block for tests I am getting an error with my @attr which reads;

```
Failure/Error: @attr = { :followed_id => @followed.id }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x00000108d0b2a0>
```

However, when I run this block in my console it works just fine. The id is set according to the @attr, and I can call .id on @followed.

Any help would be much appreciated as always!

Comment: what happens if you use `.create()` rather than `.create!()`

Comment: try using `@followed['id']` instead of `@followed.id`

Comment: I added an answer so this question can be closed `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error, the method `id` does not exist for a Hash.

To access that, you can use this:

```
@attr = { :followed_id => @followed['id'] }
```

The problem was you were trying to do `@followed.id`